# Is there a term for chained processing of collections types especially lists , sets, and maps?

Tags: scala, collections, terminology

Consider a basic collections processing sequence in `scala`:

```
val a = ((1 to 50)
  .map(_ * 4)
  .filter( _ <= 170)
  .filter(_.toString.length == 2)
  .filter (_ % 20 == 0)
  .zipWithIndex
  .map{ case(x,n) => s"Result[$n]=$x"}
  .mkString("  .. "))

  a: String = Result[0]=20  .. Result[1]=40  .. Result[2]=60  .. Result[3]=80
```

I would like a term/way to generally describe a sequence of collections processing steps. Is there such a term?

Comment: A `pipeline` maybe?

Comment: @XavierGuihot  That's not a term specific to _collections_ processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Martin Fowler uses the term [collection pipeline](https://martinfowler.com/articles/collection-pipeline/):

> Collection pipelines are a programming pattern where you organize some
>   computation as a sequence of operations which compose by taking a
>   collection as output of one operation and feeding it into the next.
>   (Common operations are filter, map, and reduce.)

IMO, this is special case of [pipe and filter](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/software-architecture-with/9781786468529/ch08s04.html) software architectural pattern:

> Pipe and Filter is a simple architectural style that connects a number
>   of components that process a stream of data, each connected to the
>   next component in the processing pipeline via a Pipe.

Comment: The first one is clearly directly apt - though I wonder if it were a _dated_ term for it. The second is not specific: the `pipe and filter` data could be generated by any type of process and thus not _collections_ specific.  I am upvoting in any case but will await other answers.